# Connect Android phone to wifly board

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

My team and i are trying to connect an android phone to a wifly board. We are having trouble getting this to connect. Can anyone verify certain phones that do not support this or do support this functionality and what we must do to be able to perform this connection? We have tried a few things and still not working. Please assist! Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. If you need further information let me know.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I am currently researching for a solution. Once found, i will post here.

Comment: I am currently looking into barnacle. This application requires rooting and will allow this type of connection. If this solves our problem i am going to take the parts out of barnacle that i need and use them in my application. I will update this question as we come closer to our solution.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have rep to comment, is wifly a serial interface?

Second, this is a good place to ask that, I understood they were inviting developers here.

#### Extra, after comment reply

As far as I have found there is no ability for serial from the android phones.

I have found sources where people mod the OS to support USB on the Go. Then you can be a USB host, which would suffice for me as usb to serial adapters are relatively easy to come by.

I am new to android and spend most my time on the Electronics and Robotics SO site, but I was interested in this feature.

#### And More!

From [prolink007](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/970/prolink007)

> [Google is looking into adding this
>   feature in a firmware release. For the
>   time being we are just looking into
>   rooting the phone and adding the
>   feature that way. Our goal is to not
>   have to root a phone for this feature
>   to be enabled. If we can figure a way
>   around this i will post here as soon
>   as possible. I will keep this updated
>   as we progress.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82)

Comment: Yes, it is a serial adapter.

Comment: That is what I remembered.

Comment: extra info added.

Comment: Well it is a wireless serial adapter. I am not sure that the usb host would be a solution to our problem, unless i am misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: you could use a simple FT232 chip to convert USB to serial. You would see a com port on the phone with drivers. This is very clean.

Comment: On that note, android serial connection would make my life very very easy, so if you find an existing method I will look forward to your information!

Comment: Google is looking into adding this feature in a firmware release. For the time being we are just looking into rooting the phone and adding the feature that way. Our goal is to not have to root a phone for this feature to be enabled. If we can figure a way around this i will post here as soon as possible. I will keep this updated as we progress.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82  That is the link to the source for this information.

Answer (score 0):

[XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com) forums may be the best place to ask for this sort of help.

Comment: lol, this is the second time that i have been redirected to another forum. Thanks, i will post it there soon, also.

Comment: @prolink007: I don't just want to redirect, but XDA is where the homies who deal with custom roms and possibly hardware hang out. Just looking for the most bang-for-your-buck question area :)